# Influxdb + Grafana + Jmeter " Data not populating in grafana"

Tags: windows, jmeter, influxdb, grafana, influxdb-python

I am trying to implement Grafana real time in windows platform. Currently I am able to capture the jmeter run data into Influxdb. I have also configured the Influxdb data source in Grafana and post I am getting message "Success
Data source is working", but I am not able to read Influxdb data into Grafana. While configuring individual graph, the 'Jmeter' measurements data is not populating in the query section.

Seems like I am missing some configuration in windows .ini file, Please can someone help me with this.

InfluxDb data:

[image]

Grafana ( data Source ):

[image]

Grafana ( Dashboard ):
[image]

Grafana ( Query ):

[image]

In the fourth Image, after selecting 'influxdb' as the panel datasource, I am not able to see any of data in the 'select measurement' box( the data from image 1 , I,e jmeter.PanoHelpDoc.a.acount'... etc)

None of the measurements data from Jmeter is populating, and I am not able to read any data from Influxdb.
Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using direct mode? Is the influx db only available from your computer and not from your grafana server? You are probably getting a CORS (cross origin) error because of that. If you open Chrome Dev Tools are you seeing any errors in the console? Will write a more complete answer, if you are seeing "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' " or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to choose "autogen" instead of "default" and then click on "select measurement", when done so you will be able to see table names from your InfluxDB data source.

Just to get you rolling, for the time being you can remove `mean()` and add `count()` which shall more or less start plotting your data in the panel.

I have attached a screenshot for your reference:

[image: Grafana Graph Settings]